# Button to redirect to another port (back button)

Tags: html

I have a website that I am developing on localhost:80 and I also have another service running on another port (3000) which I want to access once I click on a button. So I did the following:

```
 <a href="http://localhost:3000" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">New Manifest</a>
```

This works well however as soon as I start working on it and need to go back to the previous localhost port (80) and press the back button it is not redirecting me from port 3000 to port 80. The problem is that I didn't program localhost:3000, so I cannot create a button to redirect me to the previous localhost port.

Comment: you can press back button in your browser to get back localhost:80

Comment: that is not working...however I cheated this by opening in a new tab

Comment: then there is most likely some redirect taking place. you could also try to press back button multiple times, but opening in a new tab is most likely the best solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set an example for you here. You just have to paste it into your HTML website and it works. If you still want something to happen if you can not get to the last page you have to insert else and a messagebox or so with your error message.

```
<form>
      <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try add onclick="history.back()"
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What exactly should be tried?

Comment: If they can't add a regular link, how could they add a JavaScript attribute?